# print out elements of sub-array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't understand how to find the length of a subarray in Javascript. Here is an example from an exercise:

```
 var table = [
["Person",  "Age",  "City"],
["Sue",     22,     "San Francisco"],
["Joe",     45,     "Halifax"]
];
```

I have tried to print out the elements of the sub-arrays individually using these for loops:

```
for(person in table) {
    for(var i = 0; i < table[person].length; i++);
        console.log(table[person][i]);
}
```

but it seems that

```
table[person].length
```

is not valid syntax although

```
table.length
```

is valid and

```
table[person][i]
```

returns the element at the sub-index table_person_i

Comment: I can assure you that `table[person].length` is valid syntax. Why do you iterate over the array with a `for...in` loop? Using a `for` loop might fix your problem.

Comment: I prefer the for ... in syntax when iterating over arrays. I'm doing an exercise on Codecademy and it's rejecting my syntax. It's giving 'undefined' for each row. Maybe this is an issue with their interpreter?

Comment: table[person].length would be valid, if you had an array named person in the object called table. But that is not the structure you have - the structure described above is kind of a misunderstanding of arrays, or at least a weird way to use them.

Comment: Well, there are reasons why you should not use `for...in` for arrays. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description. And only because Codecademy doesn't like your code doesn't mean it is syntactically invalid.

Comment: @JAL: You are confusing `table[person]` with `table['person']`. `person` is a variable containing values such as `"0"`, `"1"`, etc. So you end up doing `table["0"].length`, exactly matches the structure. It gets the length of the first element in `table`.

Comment: Thanks Felix King - "A for...in loop does not iterate over non–enumerable properties." - developer.mozilla.org > I think that pretty much answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an array, not an object, so you can't use **for/ in** loops. Use the regular **for** loop instead.

```
//for (person in table) {

for (var person = 1; person < table.length; person++) {
    for(var i = 0; i < table[person].length; i++)
    {
        console.log(table[person][i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not 100% correct. You *can* use a for...in loop (after all, arrays are objects too) but you *shouldn't*.

Answer (score 1):

You should use nested `for` loops for this task:

```
for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
        console.log(table[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. that works, but is there a way to do it with a for(key in array) { for (i = 0; t < array[key].length; i++) { } }

Comment: `for in` loops should typically be used when iterating over objects keys, hence the `for key in` name

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (var j = 0; j<table.length; j++) 
{
     //j(th) element of table array
     for (var i = 0; i < table[j].length; i++)
     {
         //i(th) element of j(th) element array
         console.log(table[j][i]);
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks. that works, but is there a way to do it with a for(key in array) { for (i = 0; t < array[key].length; i++) { } } ?

Comment: Array elements can only be accessed with numeric index. You can use keys with js `objects`. [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804592/javascript-foreach-loop-on-associative-array-object)

Comment: @ChrisOchsenreither You should really avoid using for-in on arrays, that will unleash demons...and unreliable data (i.e iterating over other properties of the array object which you aren't expecting).

Comment: @Lior I guess that's why there's Coffeescript. I still have to learn JS though.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, your array is an array of array.
To fetch person's names, and according your example:

```
for (var i = 1; i < table.length; i++)
{
 console.log(table[i][0]); // first element of each sub array
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that there's no inner for loop to print out other elements of the subarray