# Associative array not in order

Tags: javascript, jquery

Order of associative array is like this

```
A00 = > value1
A01 = > value2
B01 = > value3
B02 = > value4
```

But after for loop order of array doesn't working

```
for (var key in obj3) {
    $("#code_list1").append(obj3[key]);
}
```

Console output is as in image
[image]

Comment: There are no associative arrays in javascript, so lets assume you really have an object, and there is no order in objects, so not seeing an ordered iteration is perfectly normal.

Comment: To add to what @adeneo said, if you instead have an array you can implement your own `sort()` logic to force the required order. Seeing the actual values you have would help provide a more concrete answer.

Comment: Please see the attached image having console output.
As I know jQuery for loop note maintaining the order of the array
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804592/javascript-foreach-loop-on-associative-array-object

Comment: Maintaining an order and being ordered are two different things. Object properties may be *ordered in no particular order*...

Answer (score 4):

Javascript objects like this do not support order, this is expected behavior.

You can use some simple methods to extract the keys list from this and sort that.

Then use the sorted list to do what you need.

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj3).sort();

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    console.log(keys[i]);
    $("#code_list1").append(obj3[keys[i]]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rmvoz6av/3/

As Robert suggested I changed this to Object.keys(), although some older IE browsers won't support this.

Comment: Perhaps [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) would be a more elegant way to extract object's enumerable keys.

Comment: How can I sort same array by value instead of key?

Answer (score 1):

**In associative arrays, the order isn't considered important**. This is part of the definition of the structure. Logistically, of course, there has to be *some* kind of ordering, so that the computer can keep track of what entries are where, but there is no guarantee that the ordering is based on anything in particular.

This makes it dangerous to simply rely on the "natural order" of elements in an associative array. It may work by coincidence, if your runtume happens to put things in the same order you want them. But coincidental functionality has a nasty habit of breaking when you least expect it: runtimes change. **To iterate over an associative array, using some kind of ordering based on the keys, it is best to sort the keys explicitly**.

In JavaScript, if you're using Objects as associative arrays, then **the `Object.keys` function provides an easy way to get at the keys in a convenient, sortable format**. Browsers support this going back as far as IE9, and it's easy to shim if you need support for earlier browsers.

```
/**
 * Determine the relative positions of two keys.
 *
 * I don't know exactly how you're determining your ordering here,
 * but unless it's basic alphabetical order, you'll need a function
 * like this for sort() to work properly.
 *
 * @param {*} a - One of the keys to compare.
 * @param {*} b - The other key to compare.
 *
 * @return {Number} The relative positions of the two keys.
 *     - If a should come before b, return a number less than 0.
 *     - If b should come before a, return a number greater than 0.
 *     - If their ordering isn't important, return 0.
 */
function compareKeys(a, b) {
    // This implementation just does what JavaScript does normally
    // for sorting, but it should illustrate how to implement your own.
    if (a < b) { return -1; }
    if (a > b) { return 1; }
    return 0;
}

// The code to iterate over the array.
var keys = Object.keys(obj3).sort(compareKeys),
    key,
    i;
for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i += 1) {
    key = keys[i];
    $("#code_list1").append(obj3[key]);
}
```