# Send array data through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have the following issue.

I'm trying to send a `AJAX` call whenever a `checkbox` is checked. The value of the `checkbox` is send to my `PHP` file where the DB will be checked to get all the data of that value.

The problem is, I would like to show the data on the page but I don't know how.

Below is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="1" value="1" /> <label for="1">Administratieve Sector</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="2" value="2" /> <label for="2">Bouw Sector</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="3" value="3" /> <label for="3">Financiele Sector</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="4" value="4" /> <label for="4">Gezondheidszorg Sector</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="5" value="5" /> <label for="5">Horeca- en toerisme Sector</label><br />
```

**JQuery:**

```
function calculate() {

    var arr = $.map($('input:checkbox:checked'), function(e, i) {
        return +e.value;
    });

    $.ajax({ 
        url: '/company/test.php',
        data: {key: arr, i: 1},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
            obj = JSON.parse(output);

            console.log(obj);
            // Don't know where to go next
        }
    });
}

calculate();

$("div[class='col-md-12'").delegate("input:checkbox[name='category[]']", 'click', calculate);
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

require_once '../core/init.php';

$v = new Vacatures();

if(isset($_POST['key']) && isset($_POST['i']) && !empty($_POST['key'])) {

    $key = $_POST['key'];
    $i = $_POST['i'];

    $vacs = $v->getFiltered($key, $i);

    echo json_encode($v->data());
    exit();
}

require_once VIEW_ROOT . '/company/test_view.php';
```

**UPDATE (Content of `obj`)**

```
[Object]0: Objectcategory: "1"company: "c1"content: "test"foto: "test"id: "2"region: ""title: "Test"__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: can you show the content of the `obj`?

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim Added to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using the following AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({ 
        url: '/company/test.php',
        data: {key: arr, i: 1},
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(output) {

            $.each(output, function(key, element) {
                $('#output').append("<li>"+element.title+"</li>");
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
$('body').append('<div><ul id="output"></ul></div>');
obj.data.forEach(function(x) {
$('#output').append("<li>"+x+"</li>");
});
```

Edit:

- was some typo in there
- forEach or $.each works only on json arrays, so you have to look whats inside your obj

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

Comment: use for loop here `for(var key in obj){ var current = obj[key] }` look more here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804592/javascript-foreach-loop-on-associative-array-object