# How to loop array one column data

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array like this.

```js
[
    {"Test": "1", "Recommendedby": "3,4,5,6"},
    {"ABC": "2", "Recommendedby": "1,2,3"},
    {"Cvb": "3", "Recommendedby": ""}
]
```

Now I need to get the `Recommendedby` column and I want to this column data means I need to send each number in recommended column data to service to get the username of that `userid`.

Please tell me how to achieve this.

Comment: your js object is not valid

Comment: can you provide expected array

Comment: This might be what you're after: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804592/javascript-foreach-loop-on-associative-array-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected use below option of looping through array with forEach

1. Use forEach to loop through array
2. Use split with comma to create another array for Recommendedby
3. Use anoher forEach to loop through Recommendedby array

```js
let arr = [{"Test":1,"Recommendedby":"3,4,5,6"},{"ABC":"2","Recommendedby":"1,2,3"},{"Cvb":"3","Recommendedby":""}]

arr.forEach(v => v.Recommendedby.split(',').forEach(val => {
  console.log("Recommended by id-", val); // make service call here to pass each id
}))
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XyNgEG?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
let array = [
    {"Test":1,"Recommendedby":"3,4,5,6"},
    {"ABC":"2","Recommendedby":"1,2,3"},
    {"Cvb":"3","Recommendedby":""}
]
```

---

```
array.map(item => item.Recommendedby.split(',').map(id => {

// this.http.getUser(id).subscribe(...)

}))
```